# Async call a method using IOS 4

Tags: ios, asynchronous, ios4

I want to call a method asynchronically. It's a method that gets HTML from a server and sets it to a `UIWebView`:

```
NSString *htmlTest = [BackendProxy getContent];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlTest baseURL: nil];
[webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

I want to start an activity indicator in the `UIWebView` during the data fetch, so I need to call `getContent` asynchronically. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Note that methods should never be prefixed with `get` unless they return values as pass-by-reference arguments.   Just call it `content`.

Comment: It is not the real name , It was just for this example because the real name is more complicated =P. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` of `NSObject`.

Like the following:

```
- (void)loadIntoWebView: (id) dummy
{

    NSString *html = [BackendProxy getContent];
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(loadingFinished:) withObject: html];
}


- (void)loadingFinished: (NSString*) html
{
   // stop activity indicator
   [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL: nil];
   [webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
}

- (void) foo
{
   // ...
   // start activity indicator
   [self performSelectorInBackground: @selector(loadIntoWebView:) withObject: nil];
}
```

Comment: You are just too quick at down-voting. I realized and fixed it just a minute before your remark.

Comment: performSelectorInBackground returns a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Any help?

Comment: It was a mistake loadIntoWebview!= loadIntoWebView. I will edit your answer

Answer (score 14):

This is a great use case for GCD, Apple's new(ish) concurrency API.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
    // Background work here
    NSLog(@"Finished work in background");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        NSLog(@"Back on main thread");
    });
});
```

Here's the documentation on [dispatch queues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1)

Comment: Advantages or disadvantages compared to performSelectorInBackground:withObject?

Comment: @Tony Advantages: finer grained control, cleaner code (in my opinion, I don't like having logic for one method so spread out.). Disadvantages: doesn't work prior to iOS 4.