# Getting users' current location in background thread for iOS 6/7

Tags: ios, asynchronous, location, background-process

Hello i have a problem with getting users current location on iOS 6/7. I need users location on app startup but it takes 6-8 seconds to get users location, and until the location is retrieved the app doesn't hide the splash screen and that is not ok (for me).

I wanted to get the users location in background using dispatch_async (GCD) but it did not change a thing :( . So i wanted to know is there a way to fi my problem. I really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance. 
Here is the code for init of my app:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

FinalMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[FinalMenuViewController alloc] init];
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                rightMenuViewController:nil];
container.panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeNone;
self.window.rootViewController = container;

if(([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)){
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}else{
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(250.0/255.0) green:(139.0/255.0) blue:(40.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
}

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[self displaySplashImage];

[self setDefaultData];

[self initLocationManager];

return YES;
}

-(void) displaySplashImage{

CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

UIImage* myImage;
NSString *imgName = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) ? @"Default-568h@2x.png" : @"Default.png";
myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
self.splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];

mainV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, screenHeight)];
[mainV addSubview:self.splashView];
[mainV setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

self.splashView.image = myImage;
self.splashView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[self.window addSubview:mainV];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:mainV];
[self removeImageView];

}
-(void) removeImageView{
if(mainV){
    [mainV removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```

--- EDIT ----
Here is the code for getting the current location

```
-(void) initManager{
locManager_ = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locManager_.delegate = self;
locManager_.distanceFilter = 50;
locManager_.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locManager_ startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_6_0){
CLLocation *loc = [locations lastObject];
GlobalVariables *vars = [GlobalVariables getInstance];
vars.currentLocatoin = loc;

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
if ([error domain] == kCLErrorDomain) {
    switch ([error code]) {
        case kCLErrorDenied:{
            NSString *msg = @"ERROR_MSG_HERE";
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            break;

        }
        case kCLErrorLocationUnknown:{
            NSString *msg = @"We were unable to find your location";
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
} else {

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854100/async-call-a-method-using-ios-4

Comment: There isn't enough information here. What do you do in the initLocationManager method?  According to this code the splash screen is removed immediately after being presented, so your app is probably stuck somewhere else. Have you used the a Instruments tool to see where?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dispatch_after` to create a delay, and after the delay is finished, start executing code that requires the user location.  Here is a sample from my own code, where I subclass `CLLocationManager` and store the updated location in a private `ivar` (which is set inside the `locationManager` delegate method in my `CLLocationManager` subclass):

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

The updated location is then accessible through a getter (`getLastUpdatedUserLocation`).

Here's the code:

```
UserLocationManager* userLocationManager = [UserLocationManager sharedLocationManager];

    [userLocationManager requestAuthorizationAndStartUpdates];

    __block CLLocation* userLocation = [userLocationManager getLastUpdatedUserLocation];

    if(userLocation == nil){

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 6.00*NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            userLocation = [userLocationManager getLastUpdatedUserLocation];


            NSLog(@"The user location after 6.00 secondss is lat: %f, long: %f",userLocation.coordinate.latitude,userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        });
    }
```